# Нумерация записей в словаре Python

Tags: python

Код ниже выводит записи словаря, но мне нужно, чтобы он еще и нумеровал все записи по порядку. Как это можно осуществить, братья?

```
ab = {  "Мама" : "8908783xx07",
        "Папа" : "8908783xr07"
}



print("Выберите действие:")
print("1)Добавить контакт")
print("2)Удалить контакт")
print("3)Просмотреть список всех контактов")
print("4)Изменить контакт")
print("5)Найти контакт")

act = input("Действие: ")

#События 3

if act == "3":
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, каких братьев вы собрались нумеровать, но если вам надо просто вывести номер записи, которую вы читаете, то почему не использовать совершенно лобовой путь?

```
i=0 
while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        i=i+1
        print(i,line, end='')
```

При большом желании вывод можно, конечно, оформить более красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, сделать значения словаря в виде списка, где, например, элемент[0] будет порядковым номером, а элемент[1] номером телефона.